# SOCKS Proxy maintain source IP

Tags: ip, tcp, socks

I am trying to maintain the source IP going through my socks proxy into the DMZ. Since my connection is TCP I can't use the typical XFF header method for reverse proxies. Is there any standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't use a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what would you recommend then? I don't want the end user to know the address of the server, so socks seemed like the way to go

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also, mobile connections are necessary, so that rules out ssh tunnels

Comment: What are you hitting in the DMZ? Is it http or something else?  That may dictate you options

Comment: @Adrien It's a palo alto firewall

Comment: Sorry, I meant what sort of service are the connections coming in to?

Comment: the reason I ask, is because if the protocol over SOCKS is http, then our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) can take the SOCKS connection, hand it over to the WWW proxy, and insert headers into it.  Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who make WinGate